# add images with "add file" in a textarea/contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I want to create a textbox where you can write text and add a photo by clicking the upload button.
The problem is that in a textarea I can't add such elements.

The other problem is the fact that if I use a contenteditable div, the photo/div inserted inside of it will also be content editable, and i don't want that. If i set the attribute contenteditable to false for the child of the editable div, it will make its parent non content editable.

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="text" name="text" class="text" wrap="hard">
    <div class="upload" contenteditable="false">
         <img id="output" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.upload {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="text" name="text" class="text" wrap="hard">
    <div class="upload" contenteditable="false">
         <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" id="output" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.upload {
  display: inline-block
}
```

add `display:inline-block` in .upload class

Comment: Yeah, it works.
But, if apply other style on  that div it won't work anymore.
Bsicly when i upload something I want to keep it at the bootom of the text area.
Something like this:
-------------------------------------------
|  text text text text text text text |
|  text text text text text text text |
|  text text text text text text text |
| IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE|
-------------------------------------------

Comment: @lok30 other style means? it would better if you attach any screenshot for reference.

Answer (score 0):

After choosing an image you can pass image data (base64 encoded string) to an image tag located in a editable div

Example:

```js
 function readURL(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                document.getElementById('myImg').setAttribute('src',e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('selImg').onchange = function () { //set up a common class
        readURL(this);
    };
```

```css
#upload {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<input class="file" type='file' id="selImg" />

<div id="upload" contenteditable>
  <img contenteditable="false" style="width:45px" id="myImg" />
  Textarea
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ga1d5bms/6/

you can set contenteditable="false" on img element to make it not editable.

Editable div look like a textarea element:
http://jsfiddle.net/uq8tpfr9/